# Hadoop : ClassNotFound Error at MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Just to state my setup before posing the question,

```
Hadoop Version : 1.0.3
```

The default WordCount example is running fine.  But when I created a new WordCount program according to this page http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.2/mapred_tutorial.html

I compiled it and jar-ed it in similar fashion as given in the tutorial. But when I ran it using :

```
/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hadoop jar wordcount.jar org.myorg.WordCount ../Space/input/ ../Space/output
```

I got the following error,

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.myorg.WordCount$Map
```

The whole error log has been pasted here : http://pastebin.com/GNbsfpg3

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 5):

There are some clues in the error messages:

> 12/07/14 18:09:38 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
>
> 12/07/14 18:09:38 WARN mapred.JobClient: No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See JobConf(Class) or JobConf#setJar(String).

You'll need to share your driver code with us (where you create and configure the job), but it appears you are not configuring the 'job jar', that is to say the job client is not given a hint as to where your code is bundled into a jar, and hence when you run your job, the classes cannot be found when the map instances actually run.

You probably want something like

```
jobConf.setJarByClass(org.myorg.WordCount.class);
```

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same problem, and got it fixed by adding the following on the main code

```
jobConf.setJarByClass(org.myorg.WordCount.class);
```

here you can find the full main function 
 Configuration conf = new Configuration();

```
    Job job = new Job(conf, "wordcount");
    job.setJarByClass(org.myorg.WordCount.class);

job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

job.waitForCompletion(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I also got the above error.
What I did is that I just copied the jar files into all nodes of the cluster and set the classpath such that every slave node can access this jar.
And this worked for me.
It might help you.

Answer (score -1):

before runJob, set conf like this:
conf.setJar("Your jar file name");
it may work, try it !